# Check if element has class only with Jasmine test framework

Tags: webdriver, jasmine

I am using `webdriverJS` and `Jasmine` to perform an end-to-end testing of a web page. I would like to test if an element has `class` under certain circumstances, but I would like to do it using methods from **pure** `jasmine`.

This is the part of the code where the issue is located:

```
describe('Header bar', function() {
    it('should show/hide elements accoding to the window position', function() {
        this.driver.executeScript('scroll(0, 1000)');
        var elemSearch = this.driver.findElements(webdriver.By.id('animatedElement, animatedElement2, animatedElement3'));
        expect(elemSearch).toContain('appear-2');
    });
})
```

Do you know if there's a way to solve this issue, or a couple of examples I could look at, **without** using extensions like `jasmine-jquery`?

Thanks in advance for your replies!

Comment: Sure, I explicitly read that, and my comment is still valid.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I should have specified that I don't want to use anything external. I guess it's not possible to do so, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks. I mean, for instance, we are using `toHaveClass` matcher but don't have `jasmine-jquery` installed. We've just extracted it's implementation and introduced our own custom `tohaveClass` jasmine matcher..

Comment: Which means that I need to create a custom matcher with `jasmine`, correct?

Comment: That would be the cleanest way and would follow the DRY principle. You then can reuse the matcher.

Comment: I guess you can post the question as answer and get the points. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want having `jasmine-jquery` or other third-party packages introducing custom jasmine matchers as a dependency, you can always extract the [`toHaveClass()` matcher implementation](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery/blob/0fb5aead85e25ddd21f9533cff48b06f035cf032/lib/jasmine-jquery.js#L369-L377) and [use it](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/custom_matcher.html). Note that having your assertion logic encapsulated inside custom matchers helps to follow the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and make your tests cleaner.

FYI, here is `toHaveClass` implementation we are currently using:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    jasmine.addMatchers({
        toHaveClass: function() {
            return {
                compare: function(actual, expected) {
                    return {
                        pass: actual.getAttribute("class").then(function(classes) {
                            return classes.split(" ").indexOf(expected) !== -1;
                        })
                    };
                }
            };
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey man! Actually I still have a question concerning this issue: the method I used doesn't work properly and the version you linked me uses `jquery`. Is there a way to code the custom matcher in pure `javascript`, `jasmine` syntax?

Comment: @d_z90 okay, makes sense. I've added the matcher we are currently using. Hope that helps.

Comment: It's the same code I have used and it appears right, but I have two problems: no matter the name of the class, it passes the test. Instead if I use `.not.toHaveClass` it crashes. I have posted a [question] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32715770/not-custom-matcher-error-jasmine about this issue, to show you exactly what I mean.