# not.custom_matcher error - Jasmine

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, jasmine

I have created a `custom matcher` in `jasmine` to verify if an element has a class or not. This is the code that I have placed in the `beforeEach()` function to define the custom matcher:

```
beforeEach(function() {

    jasmine.addMatchers({
        toHaveClass: function() {
            return {
                compare: function(actual, expected) {
                    return {
                        pass: actual.getAttribute('class').then(function(classes) {
                            return classes.split(' ').indexOf(expected) !== -1;
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    this.driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('firefox').build();
    this.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    this.driver.get('http://localhost:8000/');
});
```

Then in the `it` function `toHaveClass` works properly, but when I combine it with the `.not` method, I get a really weird mistake. This is the part of the code where I am having the error:

```
it('should not create conflicts between the headers', function() { 
    this.driver.manage().window().setSize(767, 632);
    this.driver.findElement(webdriver.By.className('navbar-toggle')).click();
    var headerBar = this.driver.findElement(webdriver.By.className('navbar-collapse'));
    this.driver.manage().window().setSize(1000, 632).then(function() {
        expect(headerBar).not.toHaveClass('in');      
    });
});
```

Do you know what could be the issue that causes the test to crash? Thanks in advance for your replies!

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like your `actual` ends `undefined` or `null`, because you avoid to return `-1`.

With the line `return classes.split(' ').indexOf(expected) !== -1;` you only return on found values, so not found values get not returned.

One experimental thing you could try is to remove the condition `!== -1`, so also a `not found` gets returned. However, I don't know the side impacts of this; it could break just at another part or (as `.not` is looking for some kind of `false`-return), it still might not work and even your positive cases with `expect().toHaveClass()` could end successful when they should fail.

The safer option I see is to create another custom matcher `toNotHaveClass` and then return only on `=== -1`, so only if a value isn't found. Basically this:

```
jasmine.addMatchers({
    toNotHaveClass: function() {
        return {
            compare: function(actual, expected) {
                return {
                    pass: actual.getAttribute('class').then(function(classes) {
                        return classes.split(' ').indexOf(expected) === -1;
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```