# How can I write an expected condition in Protractor that checks the css class?

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have a button with the id = 'public1'. When I click on that elemnt, the class state changes from ng-pristine to ng-dirty:

```
<input id="public1" class="tile-checkbox ng-valid ng-dirty> Some Text</input>
```

How can I write an expect() condition that checks for a boolean expression of a particular class?
 Such so that I can say: If the input with id 'public1' is clicked(for example) expect the class ng-dirty to be true and ng-pristine to be false/

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the [`toHaveClass()` matcher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32699366/771848):

```
var elm = element(by.id("public1"));
expect(elm).toHaveClass("ng-pristine");

elm.click();
expect(elm).toHaveClass("ng-dirty");
```

Comment: here's a follow up, if I wanted to find an element specifically by the text (no classes or attributes), how would I do so?

Comment: @KunalOjha in that case, you can use the xpath: `element(by.xpath("//input[normalize-space(.) = 'Some Text']"))`.

Comment: i get an error that suggests  "toHaveClass()  is not a function"

Comment: @KunalOjha well, it is not a built-in matcher. You have to define it - see the linked thread in the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (ES6 function .includes() is used), if you don't want to add additional matchers to jasmine:

```
let input = $('#public1');
expect(input.getAttribute('class').then(classes => classes.includes('ng-pristine') && !classes.includes('ng-dirty')).toBeTruthy('Should have "ng-pristine" class ');
input.click();
expect(input.getAttribute('class').then(classes => !classes.includes('ng-pristine') && classes.includes('ng-dirty')).toBeTruthy('Should have "ng-dirty" class after click');
```